# Aggregation in MongoDB, using unwind

Tags: mongodb

I need to aggregate all tags from records like this:

https://gist.github.com/sbassi/5642925

(there are 2 sample records in this snippet) and sort them by size (first the tag that appears with more frequency). But I don't want to take into account data that have specific "user_id" (lets say, 2,3,6 and 12).

Here is my try (just the aggregation, without filtering and sorting):

> db.user_library.aggregate(  { $unwind : "$annotations.data.tags" },  {
>   $group : { _id : "$annotations.data.tags" ,totalTag : { $sum : 1 } } }
>   )

And I got:

> { "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can't unwind an array that is nested inside another array. See [SERVER-6436](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6436)

Consider structuring the data differently, having an array field with all tags for that document or possibly unwinding annotations and then unwinding annotations.data.tags in a stacked unwind like this:

```
db.user_library.aggregate([
    { $project: { 'annotations.data.tags': 1 } },
    { $unwind: '$annotations' },
    { $unwind: '$annotations.data.tags' },
    { $group: { _id: '$annotations.data.tags', totalTag: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```